# Can HtmlUnit support navigator.mediaDevices?

Tags: htmlunit, navigator, mediadevices

I'm trying to use HtmlUnit to web-scrape a site, but the start-page requires support for *navigator.mediaDevices*, which it appears is not supported in HtmlUnit(?)

In the page returned, there is a piece of javascript, like this:

```
 if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia)
      {
          ...
          windows.stop();
      }
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Or any other similar programmable "browser" that supports this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is not supported at the moment. Please open an issue on github, adding the support is not that tricky.